# How can I fix these console.log errors after using iframe embed google map in reactjs component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-maps, npm, iframe

iframe used in react component:

```
import React from 'react';

const StoreMapLocation = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <iframe
                src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d14387.771831185173!2d102.77328521573708!3d25.640018633937373!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x36da58403c9938ef%3A0x2ad1b6679ae45280!2sJijiexiang%2C%20Xundian%20Hui%20and%20Yi%20Autonomous%20County%2C%20Kunming%2C%20Yunnan%2C%20%E0%A6%9A%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%A8%2C%20655213!5e0!3m2!1sbn!2sbd!4v1651750063366!5m2!1sbn!2sbd"
                className="h-96 w-full border-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg" allowFullScreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
        </div>
    );
};

export default StoreMapLocation;
```

**console log error:**

> ```
> google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated, use the standard addEventListener() method instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
> The feature will continue to work and there is no plan to decommission it.
> ```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's smth google gotta solve